# Вопрос по парсингу погоды в java

Tags: java, парсер, xmlparser

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему вот этот код работает: выводит в консоль table и tr

```
public class Parser {
private static Document getPage() throws IOException {
String url = "http://pogoda.spb.ru/";
Document page = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url), 3000);
return page;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
Document page = getPage();
org.jsoup.nodes.Element tableWth =  page.select("table[class=wt]").first();
System.out.println(tableWth);
String date = " ";
System.out.println(date + " Явления        Температура         Давление       Влажность        Ветер ");
} }
```

А этот код не выводит div, вместо этого выводит null:

```
public class Parser {
private static Document getPage() throws IOException {
String url = "https://yandex.ru/pogoda/21221?";
Document page = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url), 3000);
return page;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
Document page = getPage(); 
org.jsoup.nodes.Element divWth = page.select("div[class=content_row]").first();
System.out.println(divWth);
String date = " ";
System.out.println(date + "Явления     Температура     Ветер");
}}
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Потому, что в html-коде отдаваемым по ссылке https://yandex.ru/pogoda/21221 нет div'а с классом content_row. Эти данные добавляются позже, когда вы открываете страницу в браузере, с помощью javascript.

Comment: и какой выход? :-) Что нужно написать, чтобы получить погоду в консоль?

Comment: Открыть страницу через Selenium и потом скачать ее содержимое, а дальше все как было описано. Можно попробовать загрузить страницу в какой-то WebView из javafx и проделать то же самое